# Run Apache 2.4 as a Windows service and specific user

Tags: windows, apache

I managed to run Apache 2.4 on my laptop, but now I need to run it on a server. The service has to be operating under specific user account (only this user has necessary network access, etc). This user is registered in a domain and can login via dedicated password.

I thought the easiest would be to install the service:

```
httpd.exe -k install
```

and then simply modify user in services.msc:
[image]

However, then when I try to run a service I always get an error (service does not even start). Is there any other way how to solve the problem?

Comment: Guys, any ideas? This should be relatively standard problem.